# Veracrypt - Mount as a specific user

Tags: mount, veracrypt

After I mount a veracrypt volume with the root user like so:

```
veracrypt --verbose --text --protect-hidden=no --keyfiles="" /dev/sde1 /mnt/somewhere
```

All the folders and files have a permissions of rwxr-xr-x and a username:group of 1000:1000. Only root have access to it, how can I mount a veracrypt volume for a specific user?

Tried this below but it complains about "wrong fs type, bad option" and will not mount:

```
veracrypt --verbose --text --protect-hidden=no --keyfiles="" --fs-options="user,username=someone,password=something,uid=someone,gid=someone" /dev/sde1 /mnt/somewhere
```

I cannot mount it as the user because it is not in the sudoers file.

Answer (score 3):

I only had to do chown -R specificUser:specificGroup on the veracrypt volume to make it work. After unmounting and remounting, it will show the same new user.

I "created" the problem because the veracrypt volume has been made on another computer with another user which had a uid and a gid of 1000.

Comment: Directory 'directory' has ownership me:me. Then mount veracrypt with root to that directory. Now directory 'directory' has ownership root:root. `chown me:me directory` and I get `Operation not permitted`. Unmount. Directory has old ownership.